# Split Rows by count and paste it in a seperate workbook using VBA. Getting Syntax Error ; missing operator

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SplitData2()

    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim xRow As Range
    Dim SplitRow As Integer
    Dim xWs As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    SplitRow = Application.InputBox("Split Row Num", 5, Type:=1)
    Set xWs = WorkRng.Parent
    Set xRow = WorkRng.Rows(1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For i = 1 To WorkRng.Rows.Count Step SplitRow
        ResizeCount = SplitRow
        If (WorkRng.Rows.Count - xRow.Row + 1) < SplitRow Then ResizeCount = WorkRng.Rows.Count - xRow.Row + 1
        xRow.Resize(ResizeCount).Copy
        Application.Worksheets.Add After:=Application.Worksheets(Application.Worksheets.Count)
        Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Set xRow = xRow.Offset(SplitRow)
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Some information about your code and some sample data would help

Comment: Yes some information would be good. Like where is the error actually occurring?

Comment: `Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)` this makes no sense. Also, try deleting `On Error Resume Next` because that command *hides* errors but they still occur.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Sections of a Range Defined by the Number of Rows to a New Workbook

**What does it do?**

- It first opens a dialog where you enter a range manually or by selecting it.
- Then it opens another dialog and asks for the number of 'Split Rows' e.g. `5`.
- Then it creates a new workbook with the necessary number of worksheets.
- Then it copies each consecutive section of the supplied range containing 'Split Rows' number of, e.g. `5` rows, to each next worksheet in the new workbook.

**Remarks**

- I consider it safe, since it only reads in the source workbook and writes to the new workbook which stays open (no saving, deleting, overwriting...).
- Adjust the two values in the constants section if necessary.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const dstFirst As String = "A1"
    Const MinRow As Long = 5
    
    ' Define Selection Address.
    Dim Addr As String
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        Addr = Selection.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        Addr = "A1"
    End If
    
    ' Require range input.
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Application.InputBox("Split 1", "Select a Range", Addr, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Validate range input.
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Require Split Rows input.
    Dim SplitRows As Variant ' Is 'False' when cancelled.
    SplitRows = Application.InputBox("Split 2", "Enter number of Split Rows", _
        MinRow, Type:=1)
    
    ' Validate Split Rows.
    If VarType(SplitRows) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If SplitRows < MinRow Then
        MsgBox "Enter a number greater than " & MinRow - 1 & "."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Int(SplitRows) <> SplitRows Then
        MsgBox "Enter a WHOLE number greater than " & MinRow - 1 & "."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Determine (Range) Rows Count
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    ' Calculate Destination Worksheets Count
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = Int(rCount / SplitRows)
    ' Calculate Remainder Rows Count
    Dim remCount As Long: remCount = rCount Mod SplitRows
    ' Adjust Destination Worksheets Count.
    If remCount > 0 Then
        wsCount = wsCount + 1
    End If
    
    ' Add Destination Workbook.
    Dim SiNW As Long: SiNW = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    If SiNW = wsCount Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Else
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = wsCount
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add
        Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = SiNW
    End If
    
    ' Define the first Current Copy Range.
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Rows(1).Resize(SplitRows)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy data.
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To wsCount - 1 - (remCount = 0) ' In VBA 'True = -1'.
        crg.Copy wb.Worksheets(n).Range(dstFirst)
        Set crg = crg.Offset(SplitRows)
    Next n
    If remCount > 0 Then
        Set crg = crg.Resize(remCount) ' Offset already done.
        crg.Copy wb.Worksheets(n).Range(dstFirst)
    End If
    
    ' It's up to you how to save the new workbook (not enough information).
    wb.Saved = True ' To easily close without saving. Remove after testing.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Workbook created.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```

**A Brief `For Next Loop` Reminder**

```
' Result: Second = 1
Sub ForNext0()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 0 ' or - 5000
        Debug.Print "First  = " & n
    Next n
    Debug.Print "Second = " & n
End Sub

' Result: First  = 1
'         Second = 2
Sub ForNext1()
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 1
        Debug.Print "First  = " & n
    Next n
    Debug.Print "Second = " & n
End Sub
```